# In-Car Distance Tracker

Tags: sensor

I was wondering if there is any way to build a device that I can plug into my car (similar to a car insurance tracker) using a Raspberry Pi.

The only capabilities that I need to have is for the Raspberry Pi is to keep track of the distance the car has travelled, and to report that number back to an iPhone (via an app).

Comment: This is way to broad to be considered on topic here, but the idea you're looking for is an ODB-II reader. All US vehicles have them (after '95), and the protocol is pretty well defined. Connecting it to a RPi should be a relatively straightforward project.

Comment: Are you looking just for distance (a scalar value) or something to report where you are/have been - don't forget that there are relatively inexpensive GPS add-ons, and also 3-axis accelerometers (and I think position, i.e. gyroscope equivalents) sensors out there.  You could even conjure up a complete journey recording system which would gather all sorts of data (if you were in an accident, it might be able to store a short video, tell you how hard you were hit, tell you where it happened - but I suspect that then the emergency services would rather it was you - not your RPi that calls them!)

Comment: Just the distance for now! I want this to be a part of an iOS app, and I'm just assuming I can always use location services of the phone for GPS if needed in the future, but I want the distance to be measured specifically from the car (so the app can't get tricked and record distance from being in a different car). I'm just very new to working with RPi/hardware so I'm a bit lost.